# Synology DSM 6.0 command synonet --wake is not working

Tags: nas, wake-on-lan, synology

When I tried to start a computer on my network from my Synology NAS with the command below, I got an error "mac format in not correct".

Here is my code:

```
synonet --wake 00-01-02-03-04-05 eth0
```

I have also tried to placed the mac address in []. I have replaced the correct mac address in this post.

Does anyone know why I got the error?

Comment: Did you try using colons instead of hyphens in the MAC address? Like 00:01:02:03:04:05

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct syntaxt:

```
/usr/syno/sbin/synonet --wake XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX eth0;
```

If you are using a scheduled task, you need to make sure the user that runs the script as root:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is to use colons in the MAC address:

```
synonet --wake 00:01:02:03:04:05 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

On my device, simply calling `sudo synonet ...` did not work. It always displayed the help text instead of actually sending the packet. I am not sure why, but this worked:

```
/usr/syno/sbin/synonet --wake XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX eth0
```